# Android BluetoothGatt.getServices(xyz) in onServicesDiscovered returns null for Service xyz listed in onScanResult ScanRecord.getServiceUuids()

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I've been doing BLE on Android since 2013/API18/4.3.
I know what I am doing, but I can't figure out this simple problem.

I am successfully scanning BLE devices and in ScanCallback.onScanResult(...) I log ScanRecord.getServiceUuids() (seen here w/ a column index header over the manufacturer specific data):

```
01-19 18:04:57.633 10363-10442/com.foo E/MyBleScanner: T10442 parse: 0E:0E:00:00:00:57:                                                           00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-01-01
01-19 18:04:57.633 10363-10442/com.foo E/MyBleScanner: T10442 parse: 0E:0E:00:00:00:57:                                                           00-01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-00-01-02-03
01-19 18:04:57.633 10363-10442/com.foo E/MyBleScanner: T10442 parse: 0E:0E:00:00:00:57: manufacturerSpecificDataBytes[manufacturerId=0x0E0E](14)=[00-00-00-57-D6-40-00-1D-1F-00-F6-0A-BC-05]
01-19 18:04:57.634 10363-10442/com.foo E/MyBleScanner: T10442 parse: 0E:0E:00:00:00:57: serviceUuids=[0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
01-19 18:04:57.634 10363-10442/com.foo E/MyBleScanner: T10442 parse: 0E:0E:00:00:00:57: elapsedSinceLastScanTimeMillis=9
```

This scan logging is consistent and reliably shows that scanned device 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 has serviceUuids=[0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb].

Soon after scanning device 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 I use BluetoothGatt to connect to it and write a characteristic to the 0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb service.
Here is a full log of my GattHandler class (that I will one day soon open source):

```
01-19 18:04:57.118 10363-10363/com.foo I/GattHandler: T10363 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 connect(autoConnect=false, timeoutMillis=10000)
01-19 18:04:57.119 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 +connect.run(): autoConnect=false, timeoutMillis=10000
01-19 18:04:57.120 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 connect.run: +bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(...)
01-19 18:04:57.128 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 connect.run: -bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(...) returned android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@ea75169
01-19 18:04:57.129 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 pendingOperationWait: operation=Connect, timeoutMillis=10000
01-19 18:04:58.108 10363-10376/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10376 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status=0, newState=STATE_CONNECTED(2))
01-19 18:04:58.112 10363-10376/com.foo I/GattHandler: T10376 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 onConnectionStateChange: disconnect=false
01-19 18:04:58.122 10363-10375/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10375 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status=0)
```

... In onServicesDiscovered I call gatt.getServices() and report it back to a listener, MyBleDevice, which logs all of the services ...

```
01-19 18:04:58.127 10363-10363/com.foo V/MyBleDevice: T10363 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 onServiceDiscovered(service="Generic Attribute Service"(0x1801))
```

... **Notice that only one service is reported as discovered on the connected device!**
This is the very same device that reported that it had Service 0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb when it was scanned.

```
01-19 18:04:58.124 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 pendingOperationWait: operation=Connect, elapsedMillis=1004
01-19 18:04:58.124 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 pendingOperationWait: operation=Connect, elapsedMillis=1004; SIGNALED/COMPLETED
01-19 18:04:58.124 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 -connect.run(): autoConnect=false, timeoutMillis=10000
01-19 18:05:05.940 10363-10363/com.foo I/GattHandler: T10363 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 characteristicWrite(serviceUuid=0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, characteristicUuid=00002c02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, value=[1], characteristicWriteType=DefaultWithResponse, timeoutMillis=10000)
01-19 18:05:05.943 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 +characteristicWrite.run(): serviceUuid=0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, characteristicUuid=00002c02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, value=[1], characteristicWriteType=DefaultWithResponse, timeoutMillis=10000
01-19 18:05:05.944 10363-10451/com.foo E/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 characteristicWrite: gatt.getService(0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) returned null; failing
01-19 18:05:05.964 10363-10451/com.foo V/GattHandler: T10451 0E:0E:00:00:00:57 -characteristicWrite.run(): serviceUuid=0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, characteristicUuid=00002c02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, value=[1], characteristicWriteType=DefaultWithResponse, timeoutMillis=10000
```

Notice the "getService(...) returned null; failing".

This is on a Pixel XL running the latest, as of this posting, Android 7.1.
The BLE device is a custom device that works fine on non-Android BLE devices.
NOTE that this works most of the time, but not enough to comfortably ship a product.

**Any idea WTH is going on here?**

Here is the code for my GattHandler.characteristicWrite(...):

```
public void characteristicWrite(final UUID serviceUuid, final UUID characteristicUuid,
                                final byte[] value,
                                final CharacteristicWriteType characteristicWriteType,
                                final long timeoutMillis)
{
    Log.i(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                 " characteristicWrite(serviceUuid=" + serviceUuid +
                 ", characteristicUuid=" + characteristicUuid +
                 ", value=" + Arrays.toString(value) +
                 ", characteristicWriteType=" + characteristicWriteType +
                 ", timeoutMillis=" + timeoutMillis + ')');

    if (serviceUuid == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("serviceUuid must not be null");
    }

    if (characteristicUuid == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("characteristicUuid must not be null");
    }

    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must not be null");
    }

    if (!connectIfDisconnected("characteristicWrite", timeoutMillis))
    {
        return;
    }

    final GattOperation operation = GattOperation.CharacteristicWrite;

    final long startTimeMillis = timerStart(operation);

    mHandlerBackground.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Log.v(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                             " +characteristicWrite.run(): serviceUuid=" + serviceUuid +
                             ", characteristicUuid=" + characteristicUuid +
                             ", value=" + Arrays.toString(value) +
                             ", characteristicWriteType=" + characteristicWriteType +
                             ", timeoutMillis=" + timeoutMillis);

                BluetoothGatt gatt = pendingOperationWaitReset("characteristicWrite", startTimeMillis);
                if (gatt == null)
                {
                    onDeviceCharacteristicWrite(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, false);
                    return;
                }

                BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(serviceUuid);
                if (service == null)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                                 " characteristicWrite: gatt.getService(" + serviceUuid + ") returned null; failing");
                    onDeviceCharacteristicWrite(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, false);
                    return;
                }

                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);
                if (characteristic == null)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                                 " characteristicWrite: service.getCharacteristic(" + characteristicUuid +
                                 ") failed");
                    onDeviceCharacteristicWrite(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, false);
                    return;
                }

                if (characteristicWriteType != null)
                {
                    int writeType;
                    switch (characteristicWriteType)
                    {
                        case WithoutResponse:
                            writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE;
                            break;
                        case Signed:
                            writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_SIGNED;
                            break;
                        case DefaultWithResponse:
                        default:
                            writeType = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT;
                            break;
                    }
                    characteristic.setWriteType(writeType);
                }

                if (!characteristic.setValue(value))
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                                 " characteristicWrite: characteristic.setValue(" + Arrays.toString(value) +
                                 " failed for characteristic " + characteristicUuid);
                    onDeviceCharacteristicWrite(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, false);
                    return;
                }

                if (!gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic))
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                                 " characteristicWrite: gatt.characteristicWrite(...) failed for characteristic " +
                                 characteristicUuid);
                    onDeviceCharacteristicWrite(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, false);
                    return;
                }

                pendingOperationWait(operation, timeoutMillis);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.v(TAG, mDeviceAddressString +
                             " -characteristicWrite.run(): serviceUuid=" + serviceUuid +
                             ", characteristicUuid=" + characteristicUuid +
                             ", value=" + Arrays.toString(value) +
                             ", characteristicWriteType=" + characteristicWriteType +
                             ", timeoutMillis=" + timeoutMillis);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" is not even a valid registered UUID by the Bluetooth SIG. What peripheral are you connecting to? Note that only because it is advertising a service doesn't mean it actually has it in its GATT db (even though that would violate the specification).

Comment: It's a custom device built by the company I work for. The device does have this service and this works most of the time, but not enough of the time to comfortably ship a product to the public. I don't believe the "getService(...)" call itself actually communicates to the device itself, so I am of the belief this is something wrong with Android's [cached?] info on the device, and not the device itself.

Comment: If you are going to release that product you need to change the UUID to be outside the range reserved by the Bluetooth SIG. Anyway, you could take a look at the Bluetooth HCI snoop log in Wireshark to find out why the service discovery procedure fails. You should also try to connect it to another GATT implementation, for example an iOS device and see what happens there. Use appropriate app like LightBlue or nRF Connect to debug the service list also (both on iOS and Android).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your onServicesDiscovered(some stuff here) line of code. My understanding is that it looks like this public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) and comes as a result of calling gatt.discoverServices(). After I have made that call I will get all the services, not just the standard required services all peripherals must support.

Comment: In my onServicesDiscovered I just call gatt.getServices() and callback each service in the resulting array/list to a separate listener. In this case only one service, 0x1801, is listed on my device. But the advertisement said it had 0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. Later I try to write to service 0000fa25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, and getService returns null.